# Internationalization Flags code

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization

I'm using .po files to internationalize my cake php app, so far I have three languages, English which is by default, spanish and italian. Based on browser language the app displays the right translation but I also have a dropdown above for users to change languages, all of that works fine HOWEVER whenever a user logs in the dropdown shows the italian flag, even though shows the right translation, here it is:

```
<!--Language--> 
<li class="dropdown">
<?php if($this->Session->read('Config.language') == 'spa') : ?>
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <?php /*echo __('Espa&ntilde;ol');*/?> 
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('blank.gif',array('class'=>'flag flag-es')); ?>
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('controller'=>'backend/idiomas','action'=>'idioma_eng',$url3)); ?>"> <img src="img/blank.gif" class="flag flag-gb"/>    <?php echo __('English');?>   </a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('controller'=>'backend/idiomas','action'=>'idioma_ita',$url3)); ?>"> <img src="img/blank.gif" class="flag flag-it"/>    <?php echo __('Italiano');?> </a></li>
    </ul>
<?php elseif ($this->Session->read('Config.language') == 'eng') : ?>
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <?php /*echo __('English');*/?> 
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('blank.gif',array('class'=>'flag flag-gb')); ?>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('controller'=>'backend/idiomas','action'=>'idioma_spa',$url3)); ?>"> <img src="img/blank.gif" class="flag flag-es"/>    <?php echo __('Español');?> </a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('controller'=>'backend/idiomas','action'=>'idioma_ita',$url3)); ?>"> <img src="img/blank.gif" class="flag flag-it"/>    <?php echo __('Italiano');?> </a></li>
    </ul>                           
<?php elseif($this->Session->read('Config.language') == 'ita') : ?>
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <?php /*echo __('Italiano');*/?> 
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('blank.gif',array('class'=>'flag flag-it')); ?>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('controller'=>'backend/idiomas','action'=>'idioma_eng',$url3)); ?>"> <img src="img/blank.gif" class="flag flag-gb"/>    <?php echo __('English');?> </a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('controller'=>'backend/idiomas','action'=>'idioma_spa',$url3)); ?>"> <img src="img/blank.gif" class="flag flag-es"/>    <?php echo __('Español');?> </a></li>
    </ul>                                       
<?php endif; ?>
<!--End Language-->
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to translate langauge names - [you don't need to](http://flagsarenotlanguages.com/blog/best-practice-for-presenting-languages/) - use the name of the language _in_ the language (English, Español, Deutsche, Italiano).  Using flags is also another not-very-good-idea (though common). What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: Yeah I know it isn't a very good practice but It's a legacy app I'm mantaining so I'm not changing the way it is. This is cake 2.x.

I changed a few things in my code after posted by suggestion, the problem now is the dropdown doesn't show. I'm learning php though